# Run-Time Error 1004: MS Excel is refreshing some data. Please try again later using Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, runtime-error

I have a dynamic query in a sheet that has a parameter in cell C1. So, In column A there are codes, and in column b are those code descriptions and based on the value in cell C1, the query will refresh to display codes related to the value in C1. When the value in C1 changes I get a "Run-Time Error 1004: MS Excel is refreshing some data. Please try again later", every time. Is there a reason behind this? Can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Can you show VBA code and/or query you're using? Use `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:n"))` to let Excel wait for n seconds (2 digits) when data refreshing occurs.

Comment: Inside the "Search" button macro, which takes the user to a sheet that will list all of the codes and their descriptions, I have added this code to that macro:  `Sheets("department_lookup").Cells(1, 3).Value = Sheets("lookup").Cells(2, 2).Value
With Sheets("department_lookup")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(1, 3).Value, VisibleDropDown:=True
End With`